# "If(a == b):" ou "if a==b:" em Python, qual o correto?

Tags: python

Eu já vi duas maneiras de expressar condicional em python, usando ou não ().

Com ():

```
if(a):  
    print('x')
```

Sem ():

```
if a:  
    print('x')
```

Qual das duas maneiras seria o mais correto de se usar?

Comment: Acho que vai dar na mesma, porém, uma condição assim: `if bar > 2 * (1 + 2)` me parece ser mais fácil ler do que: `if (bar > 2 * (1 + 2))` mas ai é gosto.

Comment: Na pep8 e feito da seguinte maneira if foo == 'blah':

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bem como comentado, um dos princípios da linguagem Python é a legibilidade do código.

> [*Readability counts.*](https://zen-of-python.info/readability-counts.html#7)

Desta forma, ler `if a` é muito mais próximo ao natural que `if (a)`. Sem o espaço em branco separando é ainda pior, pois assemelha-se à sintaxe de chamada de funções, podendo gerar uma confusão temporária, mesmo que muito curta, ao ler o código. De fato, as três formas funcionariam da mesma maneira, então a resposta final mesmo será aquela que você preferir. Particularmente eu ficaria com a primeira e utilizaria os parenteses somente quando necessário, como, por exemplo, para definir a ordem de avaliação perante as precedências dos operadores.

Digamos que você precisa dividir uma variável `a` pelo dobro da variável `b`. Se fizer apenas `a / 2*b`, você não iria obter o resultado desejado, pois o que seria calculado seria `a/2`, resultado multiplicado por `b`. Isso ocorre por causa da precedência dos operadores que, neste caso, são as mesmas e, portanto, são avaliados da esquerda para a direita. Para obter o resultado desejado, você precisará controlar a ordem de avaliação com a utilização dos parenteses: `a / (2*b)`.